# Display select Item only if match is found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to match records from a recordset against an array of strings. If the recordset returns a match against the string then exclude those records and do not show them in the select dropdown (almost like a filter). I know I could potentially use "reject" to remove key/value pairs from a hash but I don't know how to combine it with "collect". Any help is appreciated.

```
### string to compare against
ACCOUNT_NAMES = %w(aws-1 aws-2 aws-3 aws-4)

### In the controller
def aws_accounts
   amazon_accounts_all = Amazonaccount.all
   @amazon_accounts = amazon_accounts_all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
end
```

Comment: I have not really tried anything yet. I'm trying to figure out how to exclude the items in the recordset if a match is found against the string.

Comment: here at stack overflow we prefer people to have a crack at it themselves, and come to us when you've had a go and encountered an error... it shows you've put some effort into it yourself :) have a try and see what you can come up with - it's the best way to learn. Asking for help without having tried means you are doing yourself a dis-service because next time you encounter a problem, you'll still not know how to have a go at solving a problem...

Comment: Fair enough.:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ActiveRecord provides the necessary querying tools to solve this:

```
@amazon_accounts = Amazonaccount.where.not(name: ACCOUNT_NAMES).pluck(:id, :name)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try following

```
@amazon_accounts = amazon_accounts_all.reject{|p| %w(aws-1 aws-2 aws-3 aws-4).include? p.name}.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@amazon_accounts = amazon_accounts_all.collect do |p| 
  next if %w(aws-1 aws-2 aws-3 aws-4).include? p.name
  [ p.name, p.id ]
end.compact
```

You need the `compact` because the `next if` line will return `nil` for that element, `compact` will remove all `nil` elements in the array.